# How to add another database server node in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, sharding

I've a 2 databases which I've been running on a single machine. my question is how how can I add More database server along with that I wanna use django sharding so how can I shard my data from both database according to users  means user 1 data from db1 and db2 on 1st server user 2's data on another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a router in settings:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['routers.routers.ModelDatabaseRouter']
```

in routers create file routers:

```
class ModelDatabaseRouter(object):
    """Allows each model to set its own destiny"""

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        # Specify target database with field in_db in model's Meta class
        if hasattr(model._meta, 'in_db'):
            return model._meta.in_db
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        # Specify target database with field in_db in model's Meta class
        if hasattr(model._meta, 'in_db'):
            return model._meta.in_db        
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):      
        # Specify target database with field in_db in model's Meta class
        if hasattr(model._meta, 'in_db'):
            if model._meta.in_db == db:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            # Random models that don't specify a database can only go to 'default'
            if db == 'default':
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

(from ) https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2687/

Now you can define the DB in your models like this:

```
class YourClass(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        in_db = 'api'  <-- THIS
```

The db must be defined in settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'XXXXX',
        'USER': 'XXXXX',
        'PASSWORD': 'XXXXXX',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
    'api': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'xxxx',
        'USER': 'xxxx',
        'PASSWORD': 'xxxxxx',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks done awesome man thanks, but how do I seperate Django application server and database and add other dedicated/physical server if I ever have to

Comment: I don't know if i understand you. If you want to have the DB in separate server just point parameter HOST of DATABASES at your db site

Comment: ok so let me clearly explain what do I want and what my end goal is. I want "2 separate" database servers and 1 app server. Know how to add a separate database (just configure it and add IP as a host) correct me if I'm wrong about this. Now my question is how can I move my data from current server to another one and also how can I shard my database(2 databases both postgresql) according to users. like USER 1 to 100 data on server 1 and others on server 2. and another question is that do I have to add IP if I just extend my connection and don't have separate IP of DB server

Comment: If the question topic is answered please mark the question as a solved. Open a new one with this questions. is hard to resolve what you ask in comments with no code example. Question 1 needs ModelDatabaseRouter mod and questions 2 i don't understand (my English is not very good sorry)

Comment: its ok bro you I appreciate your help.

Comment: but, if the question is solved accept the anwer or it take place at unanswered questions.